# How to i open this applications is visual studio so i can run the code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012

I have this application code on the following remote server

https://svn.reactos.org/reactos/trunk/reactos/base/applications/rapps_new/

I have tried making a windows application in visual studio and adding the files to it, but it doesn't compile.

Whats the correct way to run the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What steps have to taken to get the code to compile?

Comment: It looks like they do not supply a Visual Studio project file, so you will need to look at the CMake files and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: The link you provide is to a [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) repository. You should use Subversion (or a Subversion-compatible tool) to "check out" the source so you have it locally, then depending on the source import it into Visual Studio.

Comment: I have got the whole directory on my computer, just wanted to know how to compile it.

Comment: To compile the code i created a new windows application in visual studio. Next i added all the files in the mentioned directory to the visual studio application and tried to compile it, without success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to generate a Visual Studio solution for the project. Then you will be able to import your solution into Visual Studio and build it.

Comment: I tried to use CMake to generate binaries using the cmakelists.txt in the folder, however CMake gives an Error message "Error in configuration process, project files maybe invalid." I tried the same method with cmakelists in the https://svn.reactos.org/reactos/trunk/reactos/   (Parent Directory) which worked fine. When i import this generated solution file in VS, it would still not give me the application's code that i can run. No idea how to proceed.

Comment: Well there is a INSTALL file in the main directory which explains which tools you can use for being able to build it. By looking at the project, you probably wont be able to just build it and run it by pressing a button. You will need some specific environment to run your binaries. Unfortunately I can not help you with this.